# How to convert an .APK into an .IPA using J2ObjC

Tags: j2objc

I'm new to this and was wondering if anyone could walk me through the conversion process. I have an .APK fileand .IPA file already downloaded on my computer so that I have both base formats.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot be done: j2objc is a compiler and therefore requires Java source code, which is not included in those binary files. If the project you want to convert is open-source, then use its source code, otherwise ask the app's author for it.